# Rate of reaction and rate constant confusion

Tags: rate-equation

If we had the reaction,
$A + B$ $\rightarrow$ $C$, and $A$ was second order, and $B$ was first order, we would say that $rate = k[A]^2[B]$, but this has confused me. When we say $rate$, do we mean the rate of change of the concentration of the products, or the reactants, and if it is reactants, why is it not negative (as the reactants are decreasing wrt time)
Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: coneventionally, we define rate of the reaction as the rate of the formation of products or in other words the rate will be positive if you are going from reactants to products.  As the reactants are getting consumed, the rate of change of the reactants IS going to be negative. But their rate of disappearance will be positive. So you are right in saying that the rate of change(not disappearance) of reactants will be negative.

Comment: But the reaction is still going forward (we have defined it that way, i.e, reactants to left, arrow towards right , and products at the right, thus forward direction) so even though change in concentration of reactants is negative the rate of the reaction will be positive.

Answer (score -1):

If $A$ is a reactant, the rate $r$ of the reaction consuming $A$  is defined by :  $r$ = - ${d[A]/dt}$. Take care of the *minus* sign !

If the reaction is second-order in $A$ and first order in $B$ the rate is expressed by the following expression : $$r = - {d[A]/dt}= k [A]^2[B]$$

Comment: Alright, but say we kept $[B]$ constant, then we can say $r = k[A]^2$, where $k = k(rate) * [B]$ and then we plotted a conc time graph, we could find the rate of change of the concentration of $[A]$, would it then be acceptable to use this value to find $k (rate)$, if we knew the conc of $[B]$,

Comment: It is wrong to write that : $r = k[A]^2$ if $[B]$ is constant. No ! Whatever the values of $[A]$ and $[B]$ , the rate is always :  $ r = k[A][B]^2$

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the point I am making is that, is $r$ equal to the rate of change of the conc of the reactant, if there is one reactant, and what does it represent if the conc of one reactant is kept constant.

Comment: @nav if you keep conc of reactant constant then rate will also be constant

Comment: Only if B is in vast excess can it be considered constant (see pseudo-order reaction ),  in this case all A will be consumed and B remains effectively unchanged.